# Keep child width dynamic while not resizing parent widths

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, positioning, inline

Having an issue with the child elements of my menu resizing the parent elements and pushing down other items on the page. Right now the dropdown for items under "Services" display how we want them to, but they resize the parent and push down the divs underneath. I have tried absolute positioning of the parent while making the child position relative with no success.

[Here is my URL](http://dev.eastgreenbushlibrary.org/) (roll over "Services" in main menu):

Here is my custom CSS for the menu items I am working with:

```
uk-dropdown.uk-dropdown-navbar.uk-dropdown-width-1 {
    position: relative !important;
}
.uk-parent.uk-nav-header {
    display: inline;
}
.uk-navbar {
    max-height: 46px;
}
.uk-nav-header {
    float: left !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you out.

Give position:absolute to the child and it's parent position: relative.

Here is the code:

```
.uk-navbar-nav > li {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.uk-dropdown.uk-dropdown-navbar.uk-dropdown-width-1 {
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: While that did fix the child moving the other elements, now the child menu isn't expanding in width based on its contents like I wanted. Any ideas on how to preserve that width without changing the parent width?

Comment: Add this css 
.uk-dropdown.uk-dropdown-navbar.uk-dropdown-width-1 {
position: absolute; width:597px;
}

Comment: Thanks Manik! It's definitely looking more like how I want it to be. Do you know if there's any way I can make the dropdown width variable instead of always being that 597px? The width should be based around the headings, so as you can see with 'Services,' each heading should start new column, but some of the menus only have one column.  I'm trying to make it so the other submenus (roll over 'events' and 'find') can only be as wide as they need to be.